# Actualizar registros en Mysql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

**Hola a todos**

Actualmente estoy intentando crear un procedimiento de actualización en Mysql, y el objetivo es actualizar un campo que el usuario indique, he visto algunos ejemplos donde ponen como parámetros todos los campos de la tabla, pero al final se resultan actualizando todos y no se hasta que punto eso resulte verdaderamente eficiente, he escrito el siguiente código, quiero saber si esta bien o hay mejores alternativas.

**La tabla Dirección**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Direccion` (
  `idDireccion` INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
  idPersona int not null,
  `Pais` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  Ciudad varchar (20) null,
  `Zona` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  Direccion varchar (40) not null,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idDireccion`,idPersona),
  UNIQUE INDEX `idDireccion_UNIQUE` (`idDireccion` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `idDirc_Persona`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idPersona`)
    REFERENCES `Persona` (`idPersona`));
```

**El procedimiento**

```
delimiter $$
create procedure sp_Actualizar_Direcc (P_idPer int, P_columna int, P_Valor varchar (45))
BEGIN

if (P_columna=1) then  /*1: Pais , 2: Ciudad, 3: Zona  4: Dirreccion*/

update Direccion set Pais =P_Valor where idPersona=P_idPer;
end if;

if (P_columna=2) then
update Direccion set Ciudad=P_Valor where idPersona=P_idPer;
end if;

if (P_columna=3) then
update Direccion set Zona=P_Valor where idPersona=P_idPer;
end if;

if (P_columna=4) then
update Direccion set Direccion=P_Valor where idPersona=P_idPer;
end if;

END $$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Lo que se aprecia en tu tabla es un error de diseño. Tu tabla `Direccion` debería tener las columnas de ID de las tablas `Pais`, `Ciudad` y `Zona`, no las columnas con los nombres de esos campos, esto te impide por ejemplo reutilizar `Pais` para otras cosas. Por otra parte, la columna `idPersona` tampoco debería ir en esa tabla, porque una dirección puede pertenecer a más de una persona, deberías tener una tabla asociativa para expresar dicha relación. En cuanto a tu código, es sospechoso de violar el *principio de responsabilidad única*, quizá eso es debido a los errores de diseño antes ...

Comment: ... mencionados. Lo cierto es que es extraño el tipo de actualización que quieres emprender aquí, parecería que estás intentando resolver a nivel de código errores de diseño. Por lo general eso conduce a soluciones chapuceras que, a la larga terminan dando problemas. Cuando el diseño no es bueno, es como construir un edificio sobre arena, tarde o temprano se vendrá abajo. Replantea tu diseño y a partir de ahí, cualquier cosa podrá resolverse de la mejor manera. Con un buen diseño, quizá lo que quieres se resuelva con disparadores (`TRIGGER`), pero falta contexto para saberlo con certeza.

Comment: Es que tengo una tabla "Contactos" y se supone que cada contacto tiene su dirección y teléfono, en el diseño original estas tablas componen a la tabla principal "Contactos", pero como en Mysql se supone que no se pueden manejar las herencias, entonces no sabía cómo plasmarlo.

Comment: La herencia es algo propio de la programación orientada a objetos, no es algo que debas implementar a nivel de base de datos, donde lo que te debe preocupar es diseñar bien tus tablas. La herencia la aplicarás a nivel de código, en el lenguaje en que escribirás tu programa. En el caso que expones, en `Contactos` habría una columna `idDireccion` que sería llave foránea de la tabla `Direccion`. Como dije antes, una dirección puede pertenecer a varias personas, por tanto, es un error meter la columna `idPersona` en la tabla `Direccion`.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias, creo que como mencionabas anteriormente, sobre el principio de responsabilidad única, estaba mezclando escenarios que podrían ser solucionados con  la programación más adelante.